# Big query pagination keep returning same pageToken

Tags: google-bigquery

The query passed onto the method is only returning 10 rows for UT purposes though the table has millions of rows. In the method, I set the maxresult set to 5 so that I need to invoke the method two times then third one should return nothing however whatever I do, pagetoken is the same regardless how many rows the query returns or setmaxresult is 1 or 10.

The other thing is that it always returns the same result set though pagetoken should be for the next page.

Any clarification is highly appreciated!

UT;

```
    String query="SELECT customer_id, email_domain  FROM datamart.customer_fact limit 10;";

    List<TableRow> tr1 = bq.GetRowsBQTable(query);
    List<TableRow> tr2 = bq.GetRowsBQTable(query);
    List<TableRow> tr3 = bq.GetRowsBQTable(query);
```

The Method:

```
public List<TableRow> GetRowsBQTable(String Query) throws IOException
{
    if (isDrained) {
        isDrained=false;
        QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest().setQuery(Query);
        queryRequest.setMaxResults(maxResults);
        queryResponse = bq.jobs().query(bqProjectId, queryRequest).execute();
        if (queryResponse.getJobComplete()) {
            List<TableRow> tr= queryResponse.getRows();
            pageToken = queryResponse.getPageToken();
            return tr;
          }
    }
    else
    {
          GetQueryResultsResponse queryResults = bq.jobs()
                  .getQueryResults(bqProjectId, queryResponse.getJobReference().getJobId())
                  .setPageToken(pageToken).execute();           
          if (queryResults.getJobComplete()) {
                List<TableRow> tr= queryResponse.getRows();
                pageToken = queryResponse.getPageToken();
                return tr;
          }

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the name of a table that hits this error? If you'd rather not mention it publicly, can you e-mail it to tigani at google? This has been a known bug for a while but we haven't been able to find a reproducible scenario. Being able to look at table metadata (table size, method of creation, partition count, etc) will be very helpful to the BigQuery team in tracking down the issue.

Comment: Thank you Jordan for looking into this. I've sent the info on the email...

Answer (score 1):

Known issue on the public issue tracker:  https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=132